# Shuffling React state array containing React components

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 2 arrays (array1 and array2) containing some words. The 2 arrays are looped and, at each iteration, a React component "Sentence" (with the props being a word from each array) is pushed to the state array "sentences". The first 5 elements of the array are displayed on browser.

```
var array1 = ["hello", "some", "words", "house", "garden", "car"];
var array2 = ["other", "bag", "of", "words", "oh", "yeah"];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sentences: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let sentences = this.state.sentences.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        sentences.push(<Sentence word1={array1[i]} word2={array2[j]} />);
      }
    }
    this.setState({ sentences: sentences });
  }

  shuffle = () => {
    let temp = this.state.sentences.slice();

    for (let i = temp.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [temp[i], temp[j]] = [temp[j], temp[i]];
    }
    this.setState({ sentences: temp });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.sentences[0]}
        {this.state.sentences[1]}
        {this.state.sentences[2]}
        {this.state.sentences[3]}
        {this.state.sentences[4]}

        <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.shuffle}>
          Shuffle
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And Sentence.js

```
class Sentence extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      word1: this.props.word1,
      word2: this.props.word2
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        First word: {this.state.word1}
        <br />
        Second word: {this.state.word2}
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

}

**The issue: when shuffling the array, the order of "sentences" shown in browser doesn't change.**

(The shuffling algorithm is from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array/46161940))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I recommend you always try to use `Components` only inside of `Component.render` method and use `Array.map` for arrays inside render method instead of Referencing each children.

Hope this helps,
have nice day!

```js
const array1 = ["hello", "some", "words", "house", "garden", "car"];
const array2 = ["other", "bag", "of", "words", "oh", "yeah"];

class Sentence extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      word1: this.props.word1,
      word2: this.props.word2
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        First word: {this.state.word1}
        <br />
        Second word: {this.state.word2}
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
 }
 
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sentences: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let sentences = this.state.sentences.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        sentences.push({word1: array1[i], word2: array2[j], key: `sentence_i1${i}_j${j}`});
      }
    }
    this.setState({ sentences: sentences });
  }

  shuffle = () => {
    let temp = this.state.sentences.slice();

    for (let i = temp.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [temp[i], temp[j]] = [temp[j], temp[i]];
    }
    this.setState({ sentences: temp });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.sentences.map(props => <Sentence word1={props.word1} word2={props.word2} key={props.key} />)}

        <button variant="primary" onClick={this.shuffle}>
          Shuffle
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>React.js -- Shuffle demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This makes it work, thanks. 
Can you please clarify what do you mean by "use Components only inside of Component.render method" ? For example, my `this.state.sentences[0]` was inside the render method.

Also, why did referencing each children not work?

Comment: I mean use use `<Component />` aka JSX only inside of `.render()` method, not in lifecycle methods or in functions. Referencing each children works, i just simplified syntax for code-style (just looks a little good), you can google Best practices for react.js (but don't use everything, learn what you need and what you like). Sorry for my bad english